# JavaScript on different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, width, screen

I need to let this script run on screen sizes with a width of 794 px or higher.
For smaller screen sizes it should not run, because this makes problems with another script.

I have tried different stuff, but I don't really know how to make this happen.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Can anyone let me know, how I can adjust this to let this script just run on screen width 794 px or higher?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `window.matchMedia()` for media queries in javascript.

for example

```
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 570px)" );
if (mq.matches) {
    // window width is at less than 570px
}
else {
    // window width is greater than 570px
}
```

**For web browser support** : Please refer 
"https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/06/using-window-matchmedia-to-do-media-queries-in-javascript/"

**Update**

If you want to run the script only once and not on resizing you can use

```
if($(window).width()>=794)
{
    //do your stuffs here
}
```

Comment: Good solution. But be mindful this only works in IE 10 and above and not on IE mobile. Here is a good polyfill to support more browsers: https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/

Comment: Thank you. But there is one problem. When i open this page with 1024 px width and change the window size without reloading, my script is still runs. :/

Comment: Yeah it will because you are resizing the window. You want to run the script only once and not on resize??

Comment: Is there any way to check the size of the window also when the visitor of the page resize the browser size? Because it should just run on 794 px width or higher - not on smaller sizes. Also when the visitor resize the page without reloading.

Comment: Yes it will only run on width greater than your specified width , but everytime the user resize the window!! Please elaborate.

Comment: So it is not possible to stop this running when the client resize the window?

Comment: If you want to do so you can simply use $(window).width check and run your script. Then any time you reload the window it will run.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $( window ).resize(function(){
        if( $( window ).width() >= 794 ){
            // Your code here
        }
    });   
    $( window ).resize();    // Trigger window resize to check on load
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.width()`

**ex:**

```
if(!$(window).width()<794)
{
    //do your stuffs here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [**$(window).width()**](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

```
if($(window).width() >= yourScreenSize)
{
   // your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A non jQuery solution would look something like this

```
if (window.innerWidth > 794) {
   myFunc(); //the code that you want to run on bigger screens
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
    if( $(window).width() >= 794 )
    {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
    }//window size check ends here
});
```

});

Comment: Does this also works when the visitor resize the window? So if they load the page with 1024 width, then resize it to smaller than 794, the script stops running?

Comment: Yes, it should work. Because this code is always checking the current width of screen again whenever the click event occurs, by calling $(window).width() in the if condition