# Turn script on and off with screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, smartphone

If I have two different JavaScript files in the HTML document. Is it possible to toggle between them according to the screen size?

This means script1 is turned off in desktop, script2 is on. On the smartphone, at for example 850px, script2 turns on and script1 off.

```
script src="script1"></script

script src="script2"></script
```

Is there any possibility?

I thought about giving the script a class and use
`@media only screen and (max-width: 850px)`, but I did not come much further.

Comment: it usually helps to explain what you want to achieve and what is the problem you faced

Comment: Showing and hiding script elements doesn't result in them being loaded and unloaded. You need to show us what's in the scripts for good answers. This just isn't a good development strategy.

Comment: Basically, you've asked an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Ok I want to change one value of a JavaScript (this.threshold = 100;) according to the screensize. I want it to be one on a smartphone and 100 on desktop, but I dont know how.

Comment: `this.threshold = (screen.width > 850) ? 100 : 1` would do that.  (If you want that to update on window size changes you'd need to put it inside something watching for resize and orientationchange events.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript on different screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874551/javascript-on-different-screen-sizes)

Answer (score 2):

Check out here first to have a better understanding:

[Screen Width](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_width.asp)

[Dynamically load js file](https://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html)

What you should do is check the value of the screen's width and then based on that load the corresponding javascript file.

```
<script>
if (screen.width > 500) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'helper.js';
    head.appendChild(script);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This wouldn't result in earlier scripts being unloaded.

Comment: Yes actually trying this for bit now with those scripts, but it does not work so far

Answer (score 2):

Create a js(link that to html as a main) file which only checks for screen width and load different script according to viewport.

You can either use [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) or screen.width